# Hidden rows toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works:

```
$('#ShowAll').click(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('tr.hidden').show(); // todo: There's probably some clever toggle that could be used here.
    } else {
        $('tr.hidden').hide();
    }
});
```

Is there a one-liner I can be doing instead?
When the user clicks on the `ShowAll` `checkbox`, then show all the rows that have a class of `hidden`, else hide all the rows that have a class of `hidden`.

Comment: $('tr.hidden').setHidden(!!$(this).prop('checked')); // or just look for generic method that toggles visibility. Like set css property or something

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) exists and seems to do exactly what you want here.